# How to copy everything from USB to file system

Tags: command-line, usb, clipboard

I have mounted the USB and have successfully accessed it. On the USB are files and directories with files within them as well as .htaccess files.

I know that the terminal can't see the .htaccess files since everything in ubuntu starting with . is hidden. However, I can see them on the GUI if I enable Show Hidden Files.

Anyways, my question is, how do I copy EVERYTHING, including the .htaccess and directories while keeping the structure intact as it is on the USB to /var/www

Thanks

Comment: Although .htaccess is hidden it will still be copied using the cp -R command. (R for recursive). To see it in the terminal you can type "ls -al"

Answer (score 1):

Like the comment above says, `cp -r` will copy it, so just run `cp -r /media/<usb-name> /path/to/target`

Answer (score 0):

To use a GUI type:

Alt F2

then enter:

```
gksu nautilus
```

You can then show hidden files and copy them.